# Dojo charting + PhoneGap + Android .Error: Activity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl

Tags: android, cordova, dojox.charting

I tried the sample code given here ( index_01.html ):
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-charting/index.html

On Desktop , it is working fine but when i port it to android simulator after compiling it with phoneGap I shows the following error:

Activity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@46368a28 that was originally added here 
at Android.view.ViewRoot. .
.
.
.
.
.
.

Answer (score 0):

This type of exception comes when you try to `update in UI from the non UI thread`. Please check if you are doing so from any other thread then use `Handler` to perform any update in your app.